# ScrollView in DialogFragment, Scroll position Changed after orientation changed?

Tags: android, dialog, position, scrollview, fragment

I have a scroll view inside dialog fragment, when the orientation is changed  the scroll view position is changing to somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

To save and restore the scroll position of a ScrollView when the phone orientation changes you can do the following:

Save the current position in the onSaveInstanceState method:

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putIntArray("SCROLL_POSITION",
            new int[]{ mScrollView.getScrollX(), mScrollView.getScrollY()});
}
```

Then restore the position in the onRestoreInstanceState method, note that we need to post a runnable to the ScrollView to get this to work:

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    final int[] position = savedInstanceState.getIntArray("SCROLL_POSITION");
    if(position != null)
        mScrollView.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mScrollView.scrollTo(position[0], position[1]);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: My activity is not recreated still scrollview position is changing